# Celery beat not bouncing with fabric

Tags: python, django, fabric, celerybeat

I'm using fabric for all my deployment needs. For the most part, it works flawlessly and i'm loving it. However, there is one task which continuously fails. That is the below task:

```
def bounce_celery_beat():
    print 'Will bounce celery beat'
    run('sudo /etc/init.d/celerybeat stop')
    sleep(2)
    run('sudo /etc/init.d/celerybeat start')
    sleep(5)
```

I'm using `celerybeat` for some scheduled tasks that need to be performed on my `celery` instance. Everytime that above task is run, `celerybeat` is **NOT** running. I have to login to the server and run the task again. What am I doing wrong? Why is it that my task to bounce `celerybeat` never works?

I have read the below on this:

https://github.com/samuelclay/NewsBlur/blob/master/fabfile.py

**UPDATE**

my `/etc/init.d/celerybeat` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
# =========================================================
#  celerybeat - Starts the Celery periodic task scheduler.
# =========================================================
#
# :Usage: /etc/init.d/celerybeat {start|stop|force-reload|restart|try-restart|status}
# :Configuration file: /etc/default/celerybeat or /etc/default/celeryd
#
# See http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/cookbook/daemonizing.html#init-script-celerybeat

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          celerybeat
# Required-Start:    $network $local_fs $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $network $local_fs $remote_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: celery periodic task scheduler
### END INIT INFO

# Cannot use set -e/bash -e since the kill -0 command will abort
# abnormally in the absence of a valid process ID.
#set -e

DEFAULT_PID_FILE="/var/run/celerybeat.pid"
DEFAULT_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celerybeat.log"
DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"
DEFAULT_CELERYBEAT="celerybeat"

# /etc/init.d/ssh: start and stop the celery task worker daemon.

if test -f /etc/default/celeryd; then
    . /etc/default/celeryd
fi

if test -f /etc/default/celerybeat; then
    . /etc/default/celerybeat
fi

CELERYBEAT=${CELERYBEAT:-$DEFAULT_CELERYBEAT}
CELERYBEAT_PID_FILE=${CELERYBEAT_PID_FILE:-${CELERYBEAT_PIDFILE:-$DEFAULT_PID_FILE}}
CELERYBEAT_LOG_FILE=${CELERYBEAT_LOG_FILE:-${CELERYBEAT_LOGFILE:-$DEFAULT_LOG_FILE}}
CELERYBEAT_LOG_LEVEL=${CELERYBEAT_LOG_LEVEL:-${CELERYBEAT_LOGLEVEL:-$DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL}}

export CELERY_LOADER

CELERYBEAT_OPTS="$CELERYBEAT_OPTS -f $CELERYBEAT_LOG_FILE -l $CELERYBEAT_LOG_LEVEL"

if [ -n "$2" ]; then
    CELERYBEAT_OPTS="$CELERYBEAT_OPTS $2"
fi

CELERYBEAT_LOG_DIR=`dirname $CELERYBEAT_LOG_FILE`
CELERYBEAT_PID_DIR=`dirname $CELERYBEAT_PID_FILE`
if [ ! -d "$CELERYBEAT_LOG_DIR" ]; then
    mkdir -p $CELERYBEAT_LOG_DIR
fi
if [ ! -d "$CELERYBEAT_PID_DIR" ]; then
    mkdir -p $CELERYBEAT_PID_DIR
fi

# Extra start-stop-daemon options, like user/group.
if [ -n "$CELERYBEAT_USER" ]; then
    DAEMON_OPTS="$DAEMON_OPTS --uid $CELERYBEAT_USER"
    chown "$CELERYBEAT_USER" $CELERYBEAT_LOG_DIR $CELERYBEAT_PID_DIR
fi
if [ -n "$CELERYBEAT_GROUP" ]; then
    DAEMON_OPTS="$DAEMON_OPTS --gid $CELERYBEAT_GROUP"
    chgrp "$CELERYBEAT_GROUP" $CELERYBEAT_LOG_DIR $CELERYBEAT_PID_DIR
fi

CELERYBEAT_CHDIR=${CELERYBEAT_CHDIR:-$CELERYD_CHDIR}
if [ -n "$CELERYBEAT_CHDIR" ]; then
    DAEMON_OPTS="$DAEMON_OPTS --workdir $CELERYBEAT_CHDIR"
fi


export PATH="${PATH:+$PATH:}/usr/sbin:/sbin"

check_dev_null() {
    if [ ! -c /dev/null ]; then
        echo "/dev/null is not a character device!"
        exit 1
    fi
}

ensure_dir() {
    if [ -d "$1" ]; then
        mkdir -p "$1"
        chown $CELERYBEAT_USER:$CELERYBEAT_GROUP "$1"
        chmod 02755 "$1"
    fi
}

check_paths() {
    ensure_dir "$(dirname $CELERYBEAT_PID_FILE)"
    ensure_dir "$(dirname $CELERYBEAT_LOG_FILE)"
}


wait_pid () {
    pid=$1
    forever=1
    i=0
    while [ $forever -gt 0 ]; do
        kill -0 $pid 1>/dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
            echo "OK"
            forever=0
        else
            kill -TERM "$pid"
            i=$((i + 1))
            if [ $i -gt 60 ]; then
                echo "ERROR"
                echo "Timed out while stopping (30s)"
                forever=0
            else
                sleep 0.5
            fi
        fi
    done
}


stop_beat () {
    echo -n "Stopping celerybeat... "
    if [ -f "$CELERYBEAT_PID_FILE" ]; then
        wait_pid $(cat "$CELERYBEAT_PID_FILE")
    else
        echo "NOT RUNNING"
    fi
}

start_beat () {
    echo "Starting celerybeat..."
    if [ -n "$VIRTUALENV" ]; then
        source $VIRTUALENV/bin/activate
    fi
    $CELERYBEAT $CELERYBEAT_OPTS $DAEMON_OPTS --detach \
                --pidfile="$CELERYBEAT_PID_FILE"
}



case "$1" in
  start)
    check_dev_null
    check_paths
    start_beat
    ;;
  stop)
    check_paths
    stop_beat
    ;;
  reload|force-reload)
    echo "Use start+stop"
    ;;
  restart)
    echo "Restarting celery periodic task scheduler"
    check_paths
    stop_beat
    check_dev_null
    start_beat
    ;;

  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/celerybeat {start|stop|restart}"
    exit 1
esac

exit 0
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here is the log:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/celerybeat stop
+ DEFAULT_PID_FILE=/var/run/celerybeat.pid
+ DEFAULT_LOG_FILE=/var/log/celerybeat.log
+ DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL=INFO
+ DEFAULT_CELERYBEAT=celerybeat
+ test -f /etc/default/celeryd
+ . /etc/default/celeryd
++ CELERYD_NODES=w1
++ CELERYD_OPTS='--time-limit=7200 -E'
++ CELERYD_CHDIR=/home/ubuntu/myexamplewebsite/mywebsite
++ CELERYD_MULTI='/home/ubuntu/myexamplewebsite/mywebsite/manage.py celeryd_multi'
++ CELERYD_LOG_FILE=/var/log/celery/%n.log
++ CELERYD_PID_FILE=/var/run/celery/%n.pid
++ CELERYD_USER=www-data
++ CELERYD_GROUP=www-data
++ CELERYBEAT_CHDIR=/home/ubuntu/myexamplewebsite/mywebsite
++ CELERYBEAT='/home/ubuntu/myexamplewebsite/mywebsite/manage.py celerybeat'
++ CELERYBEAT_OPTS='-S djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
++ CELERYBEAT_LOG_LEVEL=INFO
++ CELERYBEAT_USER=www-data
++ CELERYBEAT_GROUP=www-data
++ CELERYBEAT_LOG_FILE=/var/log/celery/beat.log
++ CELERYBEAT_PID_FILE=/var/run/celery/beat.pid
++ CELERYEV='/home/ubuntu/myexamplewebsite/mywebsite/manage.py celeryev'
++ CELERYEV_USER=www-data
++ CELERYEV_GROUP=www-data
++ CELERYEV_CAM=djcelery.snapshot.Camera
++ CELERYEV_LOG_FILE=/var/log/celery/evcam.log
++ CELERYEV_PID_FILE=/var/run/celery/evcam.pid
+ test -f /etc/default/celerybeat
+ CELERYBEAT='/home/ubuntu/myexamplewebsite/mywebsite/manage.py celerybeat'
+ CELERYBEAT_PID_FILE=/var/run/celery/beat.pid
+ CELERYBEAT_LOG_FILE=/var/log/celery/beat.log
+ CELERYBEAT_LOG_LEVEL=INFO
+ export CELERY_LOADER
+ CELERYBEAT_OPTS='-S djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler -f /var/log/celery/beat.log -l INFO'
+ '[' -n '' ']'
++ dirname /var/log/celery/beat.log
+ CELERYBEAT_LOG_DIR=/var/log/celery
++ dirname /var/run/celery/beat.pid
+ CELERYBEAT_PID_DIR=/var/run/celery
+ '[' '!' -d /var/log/celery ']'
+ '[' '!' -d /var/run/celery ']'
+ '[' -n www-data ']'
+ DAEMON_OPTS=' --uid www-data'
+ chown www-data /var/log/celery /var/run/celery
+ '[' -n www-data ']'
+ DAEMON_OPTS=' --uid www-data --gid www-data'
+ chgrp www-data /var/log/celery /var/run/celery
+ CELERYBEAT_CHDIR=/home/ubuntu/myexamplewebsite/mywebsite
+ '[' -n /home/ubuntu/myexamplewebsite/mywebsite ']'
+ DAEMON_OPTS=' --uid www-data --gid www-data --workdir /home/ubuntu/myexamplewebsite/mywebsite'
+ export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
+ PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
+ case "$1" in
+ check_paths
++ dirname /var/run/celery/beat.pid
+ ensure_dir /var/run/celery
+ '[' -d /var/run/celery ']'
+ mkdir -p /var/run/celery
+ chown www-data:www-data /var/run/celery
+ chmod 02755 /var/run/celery
++ dirname /var/log/celery/beat.log
+ ensure_dir /var/log/celery
+ '[' -d /var/log/celery ']'
+ mkdir -p /var/log/celery
+ chown www-data:www-data /var/log/celery
+ chmod 02755 /var/log/celery
+ stop_beat
+ echo -n 'Stopping celerybeat... '
Stopping celerybeat... + '[' -f /var/run/celery/beat.pid ']'
++ cat /var/run/celery/beat.pid
+ wait_pid 3691
+ pid=3691
+ forever=1
+ i=0
+ '[' 1 -gt 0 ']'
+ kill -0 3691
+ '[' 0 -eq 1 ']'
+ kill -TERM 3691
+ i=1
+ '[' 1 -gt 60 ']'
+ sleep 0.5
+ '[' 1 -gt 0 ']'
+ kill -0 3691
+ '[' 1 -eq 1 ']'
+ echo OK
OK
+ forever=0
+ '[' 0 -gt 0 ']'
+ set +x


sudo /etc/init.d/celerybeat start
+ DEFAULT_PID_FILE=/var/run/celerybeat.pid
+ DEFAULT_LOG_FILE=/var/log/celerybeat.log
+ DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL=INFO
+ DEFAULT_CELERYBEAT=celerybeat
+ test -f /etc/default/celeryd
+ . /etc/default/celeryd
++ CELERYD_NODES=w1
++ CELERYD_OPTS='--time-limit=7200 -E'
++ CELERYD_CHDIR=/home/ubuntu/myexamplewebsite/mywebsite
++ CELERYD_MULTI='/home/ubuntu/myexamplewebsite/mywebsite/manage.py celeryd_multi'
++ CELERYD_LOG_FILE=/var/log/celery/%n.log
++ CELERYD_PID_FILE=/var/run/celery/%n.pid
++ CELERYD_USER=www-data
++ CELERYD_GROUP=www-data
++ CELERYBEAT_CHDIR=/home/ubuntu/myexamplewebsite/mywebsite
++ CELERYBEAT='/home/ubuntu/myexamplewebsite/mywebsite/manage.py celerybeat'
++ CELERYBEAT_OPTS='-S djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
++ CELERYBEAT_LOG_LEVEL=INFO
++ CELERYBEAT_USER=www-data
++ CELERYBEAT_GROUP=www-data
++ CELERYBEAT_LOG_FILE=/var/log/celery/beat.log
++ CELERYBEAT_PID_FILE=/var/run/celery/beat.pid
++ CELERYEV='/home/ubuntu/myexamplewebsite/mywebsite/manage.py celeryev'
++ CELERYEV_USER=www-data
++ CELERYEV_GROUP=www-data
++ CELERYEV_CAM=djcelery.snapshot.Camera
++ CELERYEV_LOG_FILE=/var/log/celery/evcam.log
++ CELERYEV_PID_FILE=/var/run/celery/evcam.pid
+ test -f /etc/default/celerybeat
+ CELERYBEAT='/home/ubuntu/myexamplewebsite/mywebsite/manage.py celerybeat'
+ CELERYBEAT_PID_FILE=/var/run/celery/beat.pid
+ CELERYBEAT_LOG_FILE=/var/log/celery/beat.log
+ CELERYBEAT_LOG_LEVEL=INFO
+ export CELERY_LOADER
+ CELERYBEAT_OPTS='-S djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler -f /var/log/celery/beat.log -l INFO'
+ '[' -n '' ']'
++ dirname /var/log/celery/beat.log
+ CELERYBEAT_LOG_DIR=/var/log/celery
++ dirname /var/run/celery/beat.pid
+ CELERYBEAT_PID_DIR=/var/run/celery
+ '[' '!' -d /var/log/celery ']'
+ '[' '!' -d /var/run/celery ']'
+ '[' -n www-data ']'
+ DAEMON_OPTS=' --uid www-data'
+ chown www-data /var/log/celery /var/run/celery
+ '[' -n www-data ']'
+ DAEMON_OPTS=' --uid www-data --gid www-data'
+ chgrp www-data /var/log/celery /var/run/celery
+ CELERYBEAT_CHDIR=/home/ubuntu/myexamplewebsite/mywebsite
+ '[' -n /home/ubuntu/myexamplewebsite/mywebsite ']'
+ DAEMON_OPTS=' --uid www-data --gid www-data --workdir /home/ubuntu/myexamplewebsite/mywebsite'
+ export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
+ PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
+ case "$1" in
+ check_dev_null
+ '[' '!' -c /dev/null ']'
+ check_paths
++ dirname /var/run/celery/beat.pid
+ ensure_dir /var/run/celery
+ '[' -d /var/run/celery ']'
+ mkdir -p /var/run/celery
+ chown www-data:www-data /var/run/celery
+ chmod 02755 /var/run/celery
++ dirname /var/log/celery/beat.log
+ ensure_dir /var/log/celery
+ '[' -d /var/log/celery ']'
+ mkdir -p /var/log/celery
+ chown www-data:www-data /var/log/celery
+ chmod 02755 /var/log/celery
+ start_beat
+ echo 'Starting celerybeat...'
Starting celerybeat...
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ /home/ubuntu/myexamplewebsite/mywebsite/manage.py celerybeat -S djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler -f /var/log/celery/beat.log -l INFO --uid www-data --gid www-data -- --pidfile=/var/run/celery/beat.pid
Overriding with Production settings...
+ set +x
```

Comment: The `fabfile.py` you linked seems to us `supervisor` to run `celery beat`, while you are using an init script. Can you add the content of your `/etc/init.d/celerybeat` script to the question?

Comment: There it is. I posted the whole file.

Comment: To debug , try running the same script manually and [add `set -x` to the top of the script to echo debug](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html) each step. By the way, you can use `/etc/init.d/celerybeat restart` function instead of stop/wait/start, stop already performs a wait (up to 30s).

Comment: I'm assuming the task fails on an error code during `celerbeat stop`, but running `fab bounce_celery_beat` would show more.

Comment: actually the same thing happens with `restart`. I changed it to `stop` and `start`. And the logs are identical when I do it myself vs when I do it through fabric.

Comment: But what DO they logs show? kindly add `set -x` to the start of your init script, run `/etc/init.d/celerybeat restart` and add the output to your question.

Comment: Done. Added that as well.

Comment: The log says celerybeat was not running and then started. Is celery running now? If so, try restarting again, is the output different now? (I.e `Fabric` simply runs that command for you, so it should behave the same)

Comment: Updated again. This time ran it again with `fabric`. It was definitely running before bouncing it.

Comment: It seems there's no problem there, what's your issue now?

Comment: Same. Despite starting with fabric I logged in an the process was not started.

Comment: Maybe it started and crashed on load? Check the logs, or run it manually (3rd line from the end of last log)